# How to append multiple values to a key using a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I want to declare a `dictName` variable. Then I'd like to implement a function, that adds values to keys of `dictName`. and I want these keys to be added in the function aswell.

So basically something like I tried, which does not work, since it only updates the last functioncall, and does not add it!:

```
dictName = dict()

def addValToDict(val1,val2):
   dictName.update([('firstkey:', [val1]),('secondKey:', [val2])])

addValToDict(5,1)
addValToDict(6,3)
addValToDict(-2,2)
```

Output I get:

```
{'firstkey:': [-2], 'secondKey': [2]}
```

Output I desire:

```
{'firstkey:': [5,6,-2], 'secondKey': [1,3,2]}
```

Comment: Now this is a good question! You have set out your requirements. You have included code that you have written yourself, no matter that it doesn't quite work. The code happens to include your input data. You have set out clearly both the actual and desired output data. Well done.

Comment: A dict contains only one value per key. Always. However, that one value can be e.g. a list if you want to have multiple things. So, make it a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below prints the required output

```
dictName = dict()

def appendValue(key, value):
    dictName.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

def addValToDict(val1,val2):
    appendValue('firstkey', val1)
    appendValue('secondKey', val2)


addValToDict(5,1)
addValToDict(6,3)
addValToDict(-2,2)

print(dictName)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks @Jon Clements. Using 'setdefault' helped me remove the `not in` comparison.

Comment: You can make use of `dict.setdefault` in your `appendValue` instead of the explicit membership test, it can just be`dictName.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
dictName = dict()
dictName['firstKey']=[]
dictName['secondKey']=[]

def addValToDict(val1,val2):
   dictName['firstKey'].append(val1)
   dictName['secondKey'].append(val2)

addValToDict(5,1)
addValToDict(6,3)
addValToDict(-2,2)
#{'secondKey': [1, 3, 2], 'firstKey': [5, 6, -2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might use a `defaultdict` of `list`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictName = defaultdict(list)

def addValToDict(val1,val2):
    dictName['firstkey'].append(val1)
    dictName['secondKey'].append(val2)
```

Comment: Using `defaultdict` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append to the current entry rather than updating it (which replaces it completely). Either of these should work for you:

```
dictName = dict(firstkey=[], secondkey=[])

def addValToDict(val1, val2):
    dictName['firstkey'].append(val1)
    dictName['secondkey'].append(val2)
```

or

```
dictName = dict()

def addValToDict(val1, val2):
    dictName.setdefault('firstkey', []).append(val1)
    dictName.setdefault('secondkey', []).append(val2)
```

If you are not sure what entries you will end up writing or reading then this is another option:

```
import collections
dictName = collections.defaultdict(list)

def addValToDict(val1, val2):
    dictName['firstkey'].append(val1)
    dictName['secondkey'].append(val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
def addValToDict(val1,val2):
   dictName['firstKey'] += [val1]
   dictName['secondKey'] += [val2]
```